# How to plot heatmap for AUC score across parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, heatmap, gridsearchcv

While performing GridSearch CV on a decision tree model I gave the values for `min_samples_split` as `[10,100,200]` and `max_depth` as `[10,20,40]`, and then I collected the **AUC scores**.

Now I want to plot a heatmap such that the **x-axis** should be indicating the `min_samples_split` and **y-axis** should be `max_depth` and the **cell values** should signify **AUC scores** that the model calculated.

But I'm unable to combine these three data: `min_samples_split`, `max_depth`, and AUC score.
Please refer to the code below:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param={'max_depth':[10,20,40],
      'min_samples_split':[10,100,200]}
decision_tree=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced')
clf=GridSearchCV(decision_tree,param,cv=3,scoring='roc_auc',return_train_score=True,n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train_setOne,Y_train)
```

and then I'm finding out the AUC scores:

```
train_AUC=clf.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
train_AUC_std=clf.cv_results_['std_train_score']
CV_AUC=clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
CV_AUC_std=clf.cv_results_['std_test_score']
```

Now I want to plot a heatmap.